# Why do I get a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have a assignment from school and I'm almost finished, only one thing left. I get a NullReferenceException every time I start the program. Everything works as it's supposed to except for the listview where the exception is thrown.

This is from the MainForm:

```
private void UpdateListView()
{
    lstReservations.Clear();

    string[] seats = new string[m_seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings((SeatManager.DisplayOption)cmboBoxListAlternitives.SelectedIndex, out seats)];

    if (seats != null && seats.Length > 0)
    {
        string[] split = new string[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < seats.Length; i++)
        {
            split = seats[i].Split('|');

            ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem(split[0]);
            newItem.SubItems.Add(split[1]);
            newItem.SubItems.Add(split[2]);
            newItem.SubItems.Add(split[3]);
            //Lägger till newItem till lstReservations
            lstReservations.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
}
```

It's this line that throws the exception:

```
seats[i].Split('|');
```

Here's the method GetSeatInfoString from the SeatManager class:

```
public int GetSeatInfoStrings(DisplayOption choice, out string[] strSeatInfoStrings)
{
    strSeatInfoStrings = null;
    int count = GetNumOfSeats(choice);

    if (count <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    strSeatInfoStrings = new string[count];

    int i = 0; //counter for return array
    //Is the element corresponding with the index empty
    for (int index = 0; index < m_totNumOfSeats; index++)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case DisplayOption.AllSeats:
                strSeatInfoStrings[index] = GetSeatInfoAt(index);
                i++;
                break;
            case DisplayOption.ReservedSeats:
                if (m_nameList[index] != null)
                {
                    strSeatInfoStrings[i] = GetSeatInfoAt(index);

                    i++;
                }
                break;
            case DisplayOption.VacantSeats:
                if (m_nameList[index] == null)
                {
                    strSeatInfoStrings[i] = GetSeatInfoAt(index);

                    i++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

I know what a NullReferenceException is but I can't find why I get it. The array seats should be filled, if that's the problem what's wrong in the method GetSeatInfoString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
string[] seats = new string[m_seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings((SeatManager.DisplayOption)
    cmboBoxListAlternitives.SelectedIndex, out seats)];
```

The order is unclear, but there are **two** assignments to `seats` here - The first via the `out`, the second with all `null`s (a new string-array).  Try instead:

```
string[] seats;
m_seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings((SeatManager.DisplayOption)
    cmboBoxListAlternitives.SelectedIndex, out seats);
```

Which only assigned via the "out".

Comment: The ordering here is precise. The method is called first, always, which means the array will always be full of `null`

Comment: @Lasse what I meant was: to the casual reader, it isn't clear (unless you have read the spec, which only a few of us do). In general, any time that is the case, re-structuring it to be unambiguous *to the reader* is easier and better than knowing the spec rules.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did as you suggested at first but didnt run the program. I thought why would the method return a integer of the length of the array when i dont need to use it. But i have to figure out why nothing is added to the listview other then blanks. No text can be seen and the header has disapeared.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to use a debugger to help track down issues. If you step through the code, you would see that `seats` contains only `null` values.

The problem is this line:

```
string[] seats = new string[m_seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings((SeatManager.DisplayOption)cmboBoxListAlternitives.SelectedIndex, out seats)];
```

The right side of the `=` must be evaluated before the assignment happens. So even though `GetSeatInfoStrings` assigns to `seats`, it gets overwritten with the assignment.

In the end all you do is:

`string[] seats = new string[some_number];`

And each element in that array will be initialized to `null`.

In a sense though, you are doing too much in your code. You are allocating the `seats` array twice. All you need to do is:

```
string[] seats;
m_seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings((SeatManager.DisplayOption)cmboBoxListAlternitives.SelectedIndex, out seats);
```